# How to make a blog type page with prev & next page functionality?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, navigation, blogs

I was wondering if I needed to learn javascript and or php to make a site that can move content from page to page as new content is added (like a blog). I was thinking of using wordpress and wipe the design and write my own css, but seems you need to do a $30 update to have access to css.

Is there a free site (like wordpress) that could help me out with the php part or whatever is needed to have this kind of functionality? How many hours would it take to learn php to get the 'blog' running correctly if I only know html/css right now, with a bit of javascript and can manage jquery plugins.

Thanks alot for any answers.

Comment: 30$ update to get access to CSS? What the...?

Comment: [WordPress is free](http://wordpress.org/download/).

Comment: Wordpress is free and you can edit, manage, add ur own theme..........

Comment: Well I'm under the Appearance -> Custom Design tab and it has a "buy upgrade" as only option. I can only swap some themes in the other menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly,  WordPress is entirely free and fully customization per your liking - no charge.

PHP would be your answer to do this, and Javascript would only help compliment the transitioning. If you've never tinkered with PHP or any other software programming language, you will spend months perfecting this. It's a whole other ball game.

But like I said, WordPress is entirely free and modifying the CSS is as well. I've never heard of a $30 charge to change WordPress CSS file.

Comment: Okay thanks. Well I guess I got to move the site to my own server to have control of css. I can only change few things like background color and header in the wordpress admin->appearance menus.

Comment: No problem. There are plenty of web hosting solutions out there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about upgrading a [WordPress.com](http://wordpress.com/) site where they host it for you and strictly control what you can do.

You want to go to [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/) - it's free and you can do whatever you like - but you do need to sort out your own hosting.